# How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in IIS7 with restrictions

Tags: asp.net, iis, cross-domain, font-face, access-control

I need to access a font file in my application from the server that I also own. It works for all browsers but Firefox, and I know that I need to add a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

So in the root of my server there is another application with web.config to which I added:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It works fine however, I am not sure what are the security issues here. Is specifying the domain that can access it a good security resolution here? I think I'd rather have this setting only for files in font folder and not the whole application. I saw a .htaccess solution for it which requires placing the file in desired folder, but how can I do it with web.config or IIS setting?

Apache:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://yourdomain.com"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Note that in some cases, `<clear />` is needed before declaring any custom headers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried to put a web.config in the desired subfolder only? Have a look at "[ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx)".

Comment: Hmm great idea, I don't know why I didn't think about this before. Thanks!

Comment: I saw a link and clicked it even didn't bothering to read the text. After half an hour I found out that I could place web.config in desired folder only. Then I returned here and read the text. Damn. Lesson learned: read the goddamned text. Thank you twomm